# Why does this regex take a long time to execute?

Tags: java, regex

I found out, that for example this line has a very very long execution time:

```
System.out.println(
        ".. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. ..  .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .. .... .. .."
        .matches("(?i)(?:.* )?\\W?([a-z0-9-_\\.]+((?: *)\\.(?: *))+(?:DE))(?:[0-9]{1,5})?")
);
```

If I reduce the amount of dots at the start of the String the execution time gets lower (seems like it's exponential). Here is the suspended thread's stack trace:

```
[Repeating text]...
Pattern$GroupTail.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4717
Pattern$Curly.match0(Matcher, int, int, CharSequence) line: 4279
Pattern$Curly.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4234
Pattern$GroupHead.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4658
Pattern$GroupHead.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4658
Pattern$Loop.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4785
Pattern$GroupTail.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4717
Pattern$GroupTail.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4717
Pattern$Curly.match0(Matcher, int, int, CharSequence) line: 4279
Pattern$Curly.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4234
Pattern$GroupHead.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4658
Pattern$Single(Pattern$BmpCharProperty).match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 3798
Pattern$GroupTail.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4717
Pattern$Curly.match0(Matcher, int, int, CharSequence) line: 4272
Pattern$Curly.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4234
Pattern$GroupHead.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4658
Pattern$GroupHead.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4658
Pattern$Loop.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4785
Pattern$GroupTail.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4717
Pattern$GroupTail.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4717
Pattern$Curly.match0(Matcher, int, int, CharSequence) line: 4272
Pattern$Curly.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4234
Pattern$GroupHead.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4658
Pattern$Single(Pattern$BmpCharProperty).match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 3798
Pattern$GroupTail.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4717
Pattern$Curly.match0(Matcher, int, int, CharSequence) line: 4279
Pattern$Curly.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4234
Pattern$GroupHead.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4658
Pattern$GroupHead.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4658
Pattern$Loop.matchInit(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4801
Pattern$Prolog.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4741
Pattern$Curly.match0(Matcher, int, int, CharSequence) line: 4272
Pattern$Curly.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4234
Pattern$GroupHead.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4658
Pattern$Ques.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4182
Pattern$BranchConn.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4568
Pattern$GroupTail.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4717
Pattern$Single(Pattern$BmpCharProperty).match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 3798
Pattern$Curly.match0(Matcher, int, int, CharSequence) line: 4272
Pattern$Curly.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4234
Pattern$GroupHead.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4658
Pattern$Branch.match(Matcher, int, CharSequence) line: 4604
Matcher.match(int, int) line: 1270
Matcher.matches() line: 604
Pattern.matches(String, CharSequence) line: 1135
String.matches(String) line: 2121
Main.main(String[]) line: 11
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: [Catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html).

Comment: You are using a lot of greedy matchers which will also heavily slow down your matching.

Comment: Two greedy inside one greedy is something HUGE.

Comment: what you want to match exactly? can you show us some input output example, or this is just a question to know the reason behind this long time?

Comment: @YCF_L it's just to know the reason behind it.

Comment: Related: [ReDoS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Regular_expression_Denial_of_Service_-_ReDoS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When pattern `x` is made optional - using `?` or `*` quantifiers (or `{0,}`) - engine has two paths to approach according to the nature of quantifier being used:

- Consumes then backtracks for other patterns (case of greediness i.e. `.*`, `.?`)
- First doesn't consume and looks immediately for other patterns (case of laziness `.*?`)

Someone probably is not aware about regular expressions or doesn't care about performance and throws `.*` wherever he needs a match somewhere in string and engines are so fast in taking steps back and forth that nothing seems weird or slow unless a pattern can not be found.

Time complexity starts at `O(n)` and continues with `O(n^2b)` where `b` is level of nesting quantifiers. So on failure number of steps an engine takes is HUGE.

To avoid such situations someone needs to consider some guiding principles:

- Specifying boundaries. If pattern should stop somewhere before digits do not do `.*`. Instead do `\D*`.
- Use conditions. You can check if pattern / letter `x` exists before running a whole match using a lookahead `^(?=[^x]*x)`. This leads to an early failure.
- Use possessive quantifiers or atomic groups (if available). These two avoid backtracks. Sometimes you do not need backtracks.
- Do not do `(.*)+` or similar patterns. Instead reconsider your requirements or at least use atomic groups `(?>.*)+`.

Your own Regular Expression isn't an exception. It suffers from much greediness and optional matches and needs a time to be restudied.

Comment: I would also advise assertions where applicable, like `^`, `$`, and `\b`.

Comment: Yes for sure. They would fall into *Specifying boundaries*.