# es-lint-security flagging an unsafe regular expression

Tags: regex, eslint

I have a regex that looks like this `/^[A-Za-z.,'-]([A-Za-z.,' -]*[A-Za-z.,'-])?$/`

I've recently added the [eslint-config-security](https://github.com/nodesecurity/eslint-plugin-security) plugin and it has flagged the above regex as unsafe due to the `detect-unsafe-regex` rule.

It does not say why it is unsafe.

Can anyone tell me why this is unsafe and what I can do to fix it?

It runs [this](https://github.com/substack/safe-regex) package

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Details:*
Finally got some time so I'll explain what's happening here. The reason is catastrophic backtracking.
I'll take the example from the blog:

You are doing something like this (x+x+)+y when doing this `([A-Za-z.,' -]*[A-Za-z.,'-])` x+x+ could've been limited to x+ but in your case, there is little difference between both the x. So a solution for you is to use `([A-Za-z.,' -]* ?)` this way regex engine won't break down the system.

What happens is stated below [from the blog](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/issues/153):

> Consider the regular expression (x+x+)+y. Let's see what happens when
>   you apply this regex to xxxxxxxxxxy. The first x+ will match all 10 x
>   characters. The second x+ fails. The first x+ then backtracks to 9
>   matches, and the second one picks up the remaining x. The group has
>   now matched once. The group repeats but fails at the first x+.When y
>   fails, the regex engine backtracks. The group has one iteration it can
>   backtrack into. The second x+ matched only one x, so it can't
>   backtrack. But the first x+ can give up one x. The second x+ promptly
>   matches xx. The group again has one iteration, fails the next one, and
>   the y fails. When y fails, the regex engine backtracks. The group has
>   one iteration it can backtrack into. The second x+ matched only one x,
>   so it can't backtrack. But the first x+ can give up one x. The second
>   x+ promptly matches xx. The group again has one iteration, fails the
>   next one, and the y fails. Backtracking again, the second x+ now has
>   one backtracking position, reducing itself to match x. The group tries
>   a second iteration. The first x+ matches but the second is stuck at
>   the end of the string. Backtracking again, the first x+ in the group's
>   first iteration reduces itself to 7 characters. The second x+ matches
>   xxx. Failing y, the second x+ is reduced to xx and then x.
>
> If you try this regex on a 10x string in RegexBuddy's debugger, it'll
>   take 2558 steps to figure out the final y is missing. For an 11x
>   string, it needs 5118 steps. For 12, it takes 10238 steps. Clearly we
>   have an exponential complexity of O(2^n) here. At 21x the debugger
>   bows out at 2.8 million steps, diagnosing a bad case of catastrophic
>   backtracking.
>
> Regex engines (like .NET) will keep going forever, while others will
>   crash with a stack overflow (like Perl, before version 5.10). Stack
>   overflows are particularly nasty on Windows since they tend to make
>   your application vanish without a trace or explanation.

[Here's the discussion about these plugins](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/issues/153)

[And great blog showing what's wrong](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: still fails with that regex

Comment: @dagda1 . is not a meta character in a character class and neither is - at the end of one. They don't need escaping

Comment: I missed a * see now. Might be I've missed some other too. Please let me know I'll fix it.

Comment: just escaping the `*` makes the linter happy, why is that?

Comment: I don' think you would be escaping the star

Comment: That's the key to your question
`[A-Za-z.,' -]*[A-Za-z.,'-]`
Makes no sense as referred in my answer please go through the link you'll get the answer @dagda1

Answer (score 4):

It seems that plugin uses word *unsafe* to demonstrate a regex which is likely to cause a [catastrophic backtracking](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html):

> detect potentially catastrophic exponential-time regular expressions by limiting the star height to 1

and your regex may cause it which you can see [here in action](https://regex101.com/r/ptgu8s/1). Please [read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50511784/1020526) to have a better insight into this problem.