# How to transform my regular expression detecting 127.0.0.1/8 IP to a safer one?

Tags: javascript, regex, eslint, codacy

To detect all IP in the `127.0.0.1/8` network , I'm using this common regular expression:

```
/^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
```

Job is done, but codacy via es-lint is detecting this regexp as unsafe.

I already read this [blog](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html), this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710707/es-lint-security-flagging-an-unsafe-regular-expression), but I'm not fluent with regexp and I don't understand all explanations.

I tried to add `[^,\r\n]` in a lot of positions but it doesn't work.

Here is a tools to test the regexp: https://regex101.com/r/YbYrcd/1

Here is my javascript code detected as unsafe regexp by eslint:

```
window.location.hostname.match(
  /^127(?:\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)){3}$/
)
```

How to transform the above regular expression to a safer one which is complient with `eslint`?

Comment: Do you have a very good reason to use a regex in the first place?

Comment: This regex is safe. Do not believe what es-lint tells you. If you just want to get rid of the warning, unwrap the quantified group, see https://regex101.com/r/YbYrcd/2.

Comment: Probably word *unsafe* refers to a different definition in this context. Your regex is totally fine.

Comment: I see the one https://regex101.com/r/YbYrcd/1 is not matching ```127.0.0.1```. So it's probably unsafe. @WiktorStribiżew has given a more safer regex

Comment: `Here is a tools to test the regexp` - you're missing a `.` in that - see https://regex101.com/r/YbYrcd/3

Comment: I'm rather wondering what sort of hardware you have which can support 17 million hosts on the loopback network. It would have been helpful if you'd supplied a description of how exacting the match needs to be - parsing binary numbers represented in ASCII decimals using regular expressions is not trivial.

Comment: @Robill : This code is generated by reactjs in the `registerServiceWorker.js` file when dev team creates a new reactjs project. Final clients want to have a "A" score application. So I am trying to pull a request to update this regexp on reactjs project.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : Yes it seems to me that regexp was already safe, but you know how final clients react with security indicators... Your update rid of the warning. Thanks a lot. Do you want to post your answer? So, I will accept it.

Comment: @user202729 : Yes, it should be "detecting this regex as unsafe". Post is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eslint produces a warning because your regex contains a quantified group containing alternation operators and quantifiers inside. In reality, since the limiting quantifier only "repeats" the pattern three times, the pattern is rather safe, but Eslint cannot deduce that.

To get rid of the warning, unwrap/unroll the quantified group (=repeat the `.` + octet pattern three times):

```
/^127\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YbYrcd/2)