# How to fix Dynamically building strings at runtime may introduce security vulnerabilities in ESlint?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I am using react and typescript and I ran into this issue with my function

```
  const FixHighlightedText = (search_text:string, text:string):string => {
    const tokens = search_text.split(' ');
    const token_list = combinations.GetAllCombinations(tokens);
    text = text.replace(/<ddd\/>/g, '');
    for(let i=0; i<token_list.length; i++) {
      text = text.replace(new RegExp(token_list[i], "gi"), (match) => `<b>${match}</b>`);
    }
    return text + "...";
  };
```

but I get back this warning

```
[09:35:30] Warning - lint - src\webparts\documentationViewer\components\DocumentationViewer.tsx(147,27): error @rushstack/security/no-unsafe-regexp: Regular expressions should be constructed from string constants. Dynamically building strings at runtime may introduce security vulnerabilities, performance concerns, and bugs involving incorrect escaping of special characters.
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710707/es-lint-security-flagging-an-unsafe-regular-expression

Comment: that does not help